# How to add a timestamp to bash script log?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, shell

I have a constantly running script that I output to a log file:

```
script.sh >> /var/log/logfile
```

I'd like to add a timestamp before each line that is appended to the log.  Like:

```
Sat Sep 10 21:33:06 UTC 2011 The server has booted up.  Hmmph.
```

Is there any jujitsu I can use?

Comment: See this questin.  http://serverfault.com/questions/80749/ping-replacement-that-shows-real-time. A couple answer would apply here.

Comment: For an awk/gawk solution see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text

Comment: Here is a comprehensive implementation of logging for bash: https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

Comment: Best local answer is @ChuckCottrill's https://serverfault.com/a/835534/137665 .
`script.sh | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' >> /var/log/logfile`

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can pipe the script's output through a loop that prefixes the current date and time:

```
./script.sh | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line"; done >>/var/log/logfile
```

If you'll be using this a lot, it's easy to make a bash function to handle the loop:

```
adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line";
    done
}

./thisscript.sh | adddate >>/var/log/logfile
./thatscript.sh | adddate >>/var/log/logfile
./theotherscript.sh | adddate >>/var/log/logfile
```

Comment: What is "IFS= " for?

Comment: @Nils it's a trick to prevent `read` from trimming whitespace at the beginning and and of the line.  It sets IFS (bash's Internal Field Separator, basically a list of whitespace characters) to empty for the `read` command.

Comment: ...and -r ignores the escape-character "\". This should really work in all cases - great pice of scripting.

Comment: @Nils it's not completely bulletproof, since some implementations of `echo` interpret escape sequences.  If you *really* want it not to mess with the content (other than adding dates), replace the `echo` command with `printf "%s %s\n" "$(date)" "$line"`

Comment: This is so cool!

Comment: You might be interested on a [ISO-8601 compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7216394/4970442) date/timestamp: `date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` or maybe more pretty `date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`.

Comment: while this script works as expected, it spawns a new process (execute `date`) for _each_ log line, which can be a massive drawback depending on your machine and the amount of logs. I would rather suggest to use `ts` if available, see the answer from @willem

Comment: @PabloBianchi `date [-u] -Iseconds` or `date [-u] --iso-8601=seconds` will accomplish the same thing without manually recreating the format.  Per [this question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164826/date-command-iso-8601-option), this has been a documented option since v8.15 of coreutils.  It doesn't appear to use a 'Z' for UTC, however, which is mildly annoying IMO.

Comment: How to preserve color?

Comment: @SohailSi This shouldn't remove color (i.e. any color-setting terminal control escape sequences), but many commands only output color-setting escape sequences when their output is going directly to a terminal. You may need to tell the command producing the initial output to include color sequences even though its output is going to a pipe (e.g. `grep --color=always`).

Answer (score 99):

See `ts` from the Ubuntu `moreutils` package:

```
command | ts
```

Or, if `$command` does automatic buffering (requires `expect-dev` package):

```
unbuffer command | ts
```

Comment: FYI, `unbuffer` is in the "expect" package on Arch Linux.

Comment: This is great, but it is not available on AL2.

Comment: On Void Linux, the `ts` command is installed as `moreutils_ts`

Answer (score 55):

The [**date**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command will provide that information

```
date -u
Sat Sep 10 22:39:24 UTC 2011
```

so you can

```
echo $(date -u) "Some message or other"
```

is that what you wanted ?

Comment: Using the date command was kind of what I had in mind, but I can't really add that to the script itself, so what I'm looking for is a way to change this line: "script.sh >> /var/log/logfile" to append the date.

Comment: In that case redirect the output of your script to a named pipe and have a daemon listening for output which takes the script output and adds a date before writing it to a log file. You can probably modify the [**script I wrote**](http://serverfault.com/questions/189477/rotate-logs-of-a-dumb-non-interactive-application/189880#189880) here to do this. I would do it because it interests me but it's late in the UK and I have an early start tomorrow.

Answer (score 13):

Make a `config.sh` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LOGFILE="/path/to/log.log"
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
```

When you need to send to log file use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /path/to/config.sh

echo "$TIMESTAMP Say what you are doing" >> $LOGFILE

do_what_you_want >> $LOGFILE
```

Log file will looks like

```
2013-02-03 18:22:30 Say what you are doing
```

So it will be easy to sort by date

Comment: Your ''config.sh'' will run ''date'' exactly once, on ''source .../config.sh''.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply **echo** the command outputs to the logfile. ie,

```
echo "`date -u` `./script.sh`" >> /var/log/logfile
```

It really works :)

**Example:**

```
[sparx@E1]$ ./script.sh 
Hello Worldy
[sparx@E1]$ echo "`date -u` `./script.sh`" >> logfile.txt
[sparx@E1]$ cat logfile.txt 
Mon Sep 12 20:18:28 UTC 2011 Hello Worldy
[sparx@E1]$
```

Comment: What are you getting when you execute the command ?

Comment: That puts a timestamp before the entire output of ''./script.sh'', not before each line.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer https://serverfault.com/a/310104 can be a bit slow, if a lot of lines have to be processed, with the overhead of starting the `date` process allowing about 50 lines per second in Ubuntu, and only about 10-20 in Cygwin.

When `bash` can be assumed a faster alternative would be the `printf` builtin with its `%(...)T` format specifier. Compare

```
>> while true; do date; done | uniq -c
     47 Wed Nov  9 23:17:18 STD 2016
     56 Wed Nov  9 23:17:19 STD 2016
     55 Wed Nov  9 23:17:20 STD 2016
     51 Wed Nov  9 23:17:21 STD 2016
     50 Wed Nov  9 23:17:22 STD 2016

>> while true; do printf '%(%F %T)T\n'; done | uniq -c
  20300 2016-11-09 23:17:56
  31767 2016-11-09 23:17:57
  32109 2016-11-09 23:17:58
  31036 2016-11-09 23:17:59
  30714 2016-11-09 23:18:00
```

As pointed out after the original answer (see below), an awk-based solution is the most efficient, when really high throughput is needed, and it has the advantage of not being bash-specific syntax. (For instance, in `zsh`, the `%(..)T` format does not work.)

---

*Remark.* On my current OpenSuse work PC (July 2021) performance is significantly up, doing 1200 lines per second with `date` and 265,000 lines per second with `printf`. Not entirely clear, how this particular performance jumped by almost two orders of magnitude compared to my laptop from 5 years ago.

---

*Update.* Just adding new benchmarks (still same OpenSuse PC, May 2023), and adding `awk` solution, as suggested by StéphaneGourichon in the comments.

```
>>> yes | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date) ${line}"; done | uniq -c 
    561 Tue 09 May 2023 10:20:39 AM CEST y
    704 Tue 09 May 2023 10:20:40 AM CEST y
    695 Tue 09 May 2023 10:20:41 AM CEST y
    696 Tue 09 May 2023 10:20:42 AM CEST y
    
>>> yes | while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%(%F %T)T: %s\n" -1 "${line}"; done | uniq -c 
   6935 2023-05-09 10:23:21: y
  22962 2023-05-09 10:23:22: y
  20426 2023-05-09 10:23:23: y
  18212 2023-05-09 10:23:24: y
  18406 2023-05-09 10:23:25: y

>>> yes | awk '{print strftime("%F %T"), $0}' | uniq -c
 520932 2023-05-09 10:24:51 y
 587067 2023-05-09 10:24:52 y
 586600 2023-05-09 10:24:53 y
 587226 2023-05-09 10:24:54 y
 579186 2023-05-09 10:24:55 y
 572274 2023-05-09 10:24:56 y
```

Like the while-loop based variants, one date is added per line, and within-line whitespace is preserved unmodified.

```
>>> yes | sed 's/y/This is a longer text/' | awk '{print strftime("%F %T"), $0}' | uniq -c
 331324 2023-05-09 10:28:09 This is a longer text
 504857 2023-05-09 10:28:10 This is a longer text
```

Comment: This answer deserves more attention. Even though using external program `date` might now be such a performance problem on nowadays machines, when a tool has everything inside, better not complicate with more tools. Plus this answers provide a simple and locally reproducible performance measurement (on my machine I get 700-1000 per second and 150k-170k per second). More answers should be of such quality.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon There are actually cases where it can make a huge performance difference still. E.g. I use this construct for adding timing information to stdout with `someprogram | while true; do date; done | uniq -c` . If a program produces hundreds of lines per second, calling `date` for each slows the performance down, while using the builtin does not. Though curiously, right now even the builtin produces only about 4000 lines per `uniq -c` for me... Could be that I tested on Linux back then.

Comment: yes we agree, no repeated external program will be faster. When performance is really important, no repeated bash construct will be even faster. GNU `awk` based solution may provide the best, see @ChuckCottrill's answer https://serverfault.com/a/835534/137665 On my machine I get 3.5x speed gain by replacing `yes |head -5000000 | while true; do printf '%(%F %T)T\n'; done | uniq -c` with `yes |head -5000000 | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' >> /var/log/logfile` .

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
timestamp()
{
 date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
}
```

Call this timestamp function in every echo command:

```
echo "$(timestamp): write your log here" >> /var/log/<logfile>.log
```

Comment: @ shazbot:Thanks for editing, that was a typo error, i didnt notice.

Answer (score 6):

### Short answer formatted to fit the question

```
script.sh | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' >> /var/log/logfile
```

### Explanation

`awk` runs fast **and** is able to work as Unix pipe filter **and** print date by itself.

```
gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
```

Let's benchmark it:

```
yes |head -5000000 |gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' |uniq -c
 461592 [2017-02-28 19:46:44] y
 488555 [2017-02-28 19:46:45] y
 491205 [2017-02-28 19:46:46] y
 498568 [2017-02-28 19:46:47] y
 502605 [2017-02-28 19:46:48] y
 494048 [2017-02-28 19:46:49] y
 493299 [2017-02-28 19:46:50] y
 498005 [2017-02-28 19:46:51] y
 502916 [2017-02-28 19:46:52] y
 495550 [2017-02-28 19:46:53] y
  73657 [2017-02-28 19:46:54] y
```

### Additional information

Sed appears to runs much faster,

```
sed -e "s/^/$(date -R) /"

yes |head -5000000 |sed -e "s/^/$(date -R) /" |uniq -c
5000000 Tue, 28 Feb 2017 19:57:00 -0500 y
```

However, on closer inspection, set does not seem to change time,

```
vmstat 1 | sed -e "s/^/$(date -R) /"
```

Because `date` (which is slower by the way) gets called only once.

Comment: this is because it is bash evaluating `"s/^/$(date -R) /"` and running date once before sed. Sed is passed a static string.

Comment: Plain bash: `yes | head -5000000 | while read line; do echo $((SECONDS)); done | uniq -c` which is much slower than gawk. `ts` utility has similar performance as bash loop.

Comment: Perl: `yes |head -5000000 |perl -ne 'print localtime."\t".$_' |uniq -c` which is slightly slower than awk.

Answer (score 5):

You mean like:

```
(date && script.sh) >> /var/log/logfile
```

Comment: My god, people, everyone is doing back tick replacement, named pipes, etc.  Just enclose both the date command and the script in parens! The guy who has the function has a legit case if there's multi-line output and the log needs to look pretty with the date on every line, but most of these solutions are overkill that doesn't use shell semantics.

Comment: That will only add the timestamp once per execution of `script.sh`. The OP needs a timestamp per line.

Comment: although this doesn't answer the OP question I still found it useful info.

Answer (score 3):

This script print the output in terminal and also saves in log file.

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_LOG=/var/log/output.log

echolog(){
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then cat - | while read -r message
        do
                echo "$(date +"[%F %T %Z] -") $message" | tee -a $MY_LOG
            done
    else
        echo -n "$(date +'[%F %T %Z]') - " | tee -a $MY_LOG
        echo $* | tee -a $MY_LOG
    fi
}

echolog "My script is starting"
whoami | echolog
```

Sample output:

```
[2017-10-29 19:46:36 UTC] - My script is starting
[2017-10-29 19:46:36 UTC] - root
```

Comment: your first date command should use single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to setup a function to call each time you want to output data in your code:

```
PrintLog(){
  information=$1
  logFile=$2
  #echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)'" ${information} >> $logFile
  #Improve performance by using printf instead of date
  echo "$(printf '%(%F %T)T')" ${1} >> ${logFile}
}
```

Then every time in your code you want to send it to the log file call

```
PrintLog "Stuff you want to add..." ${LogFileVariable}
```

Easy peasy....

Comment: You're missing a close paren

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer missed that

Answer (score 3):

At the beggining of your script add the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
PS4='[\D{%d.%m.%y} \t]'
```

This will add date and time to every command and also it will write it out- eg:
echo "GIT_BRANCH: $GIT_BRANCH"
[11.12.20 12:50:46]echo 'GIT_BRANCH: master'

references and descriptions:
Bash options:
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

Bash PS variables:
[https://linoxide.com/how-tos/change-bash-prompt-variable-ps1/#:~:text=PS1%3A%20environment%20variable%20which%20contains,long%20command%20in%20many%20lines](https://linoxide.com/how-tos/change-bash-prompt-variable-ps1/#:%7E:text=PS1%3A%20environment%20variable%20which%20contains,long%20command%20in%20many%20lines).

Comment: This gives a weird result on subcommands with the time ```bash-3.2$ PS4='\t '
bash-3.2$ echo $(echo hi)
hi
bash-3.2$ set -x
bash-3.2$ echo $(echo hi)
113:18:04 echo hi
13:18:04 echo hi
hi
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the system logger, which is available on every linux instance, docker container, mac os, etc etc.

```sh
$ uname -a
Darwin xxx xxxx Darwin Kernel Version xxx: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xxx/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 xxx Darwin
$ printf "%s\n" one two | logger -sp DEBUG 
Jul  4 00:51:42  christian[19358] <Debug>: one
Jul  4 00:51:42  christian[19358] <Debug>: two
$ docker run -it --rm debian sh -c 'printf "%s\n" one two | logger --socket-errors=off -sp WARN'
<12>Jul  3 23:08:21 root: one
<12>Jul  3 23:08:21 root: two
```

It's old and as fundamentally a part of linux as grep, sed, awk, etc and is written in c, which makes it a faster and better option than anything above, though `ts` is a better fit to your question. Do **not** use someone's self-roll; logging is too important and complex to leave to amateurish solution or something ad hoc.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html
https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/logger.c

Answer (score 1):

The below is my log file contents

```
xiongyu@ubuntu:~/search_start_sh$ tail restart_scrape.log 

2017-08-25 21:10:09 scrape_yy_news_main.py got down, now I will restart it

2017-08-25 21:10:09 check_yy_news_warn.py got down, now I will restart it

2017-08-25 21:14:53 scrape_yy_news_main.py got down, now I will restart it
```

some of my shell contents is as below

```
log_file="restart_scrape.log"
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo "$TIMESTAMP $search_py_file got down, now I will restart it" | tee -a $log_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply do this (`buddy` variable is just an example, you can put anything there):

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$( date +%Y%m%d-%H%M-%S )
buddy=`cat /proc/buddyinfo | grep Normal`
echo "$now, $buddy" >> /home/myuser/buddyinfo-logger.log
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that using xargs with printf works well and is fast.

```sh
timestamp="$(date -Iseconds)"
ls | xargs -d '\n' -l printf '%s: %s' "$timestamp" 1>&2
```

I write to stderr just not to pollute the stdout.

I have made a logging utility written in bash that I use in my bash scripts:

https://github.com/bas080/logger

It has more features than the example above.

Answer (score 1):

To have have a short log suffix like `| log` I came up with this.

```
function log() {
  while read
  do
    echo $(date +%F\ %T) $REPLY >> /tmp/log.log
  done
}
echo foo | log
head -n 3 /proc/cpuinfo | log
```

Example output:

```
2023-01-29 10:46:58 foo
2023-01-29 10:46:58 processor : 0
2023-01-29 10:46:59 vendor_id : GenuineIntel
2023-01-29 10:46:59 cpu family : 6
```

*Inspired by others and twisted...*

Answer (score 0):

Pipe a "sed":

```
script.sh | sed "s|^|$('date') :: |" >> /var/log/logfile
```

Comment: as for the other answer, this is just bash running date once. sed is not updating the time per line.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my servers do not support `ts`, so I came up with a `sed | xargs date | tee` combination to timestamp all my script's output.

In addition I prefer the way to set common settings and the log mechanism in a separate script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# disable history expansion
set +H

# log all output
exec &> >(stdbuf -o0 sed 's/%/%%/g' | xargs -d '\n' -I {} date '+%F %T {}' | tee -a "/var/log/${0//\//_}.log" )

# log execution start
echo "Script execution started..."
```

Now I include this in all scripts and they will log `stdout` and `stderr` with a timestamp to /var/log/_usr_local_bin_scriptname.log:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /usr/local/lib/bash/common.sh

# print working dir to log file and console
pwd

# errors are logged as well
ls /does/not/exist
```

Of course you could suppress the additional output to the console by [redirecting stdout of `tee` to `/dev/null`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436523/101920). And you should [use logrotate](https://superuser.com/a/1341958/129262) to automatically compress the logs.