# How to prefix logs with date and time

Tags: logging, command-line-interface, cron, time

How to prefix all logs with date time before they are written to the log file?

Let's say I am logging unexpected errors in crontab in the following way:

`python somescript.py >> /tmp/output.log 2>&1`

Is there an easy way to prefix (perhaps by piping through some third party command) all lines in the output.log with the date time so I would know when a given error happened?

Comment: Maybe some of the answers from this will apply to you?  http://serverfault.com/questions/80749/ping-replacement-that-shows-real-time

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [logger (1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) (usually `/bin/logger`), and simply send everything to syslog:

```
python somescript.py | logger -t somescript.py
```

Syslog will automatically prepend the time/date to the log entry for you, and write this information to `/var/log/messages` (or whatever is specified in `/etc/syslog.conf`).

And this way, you have the advantage of all of the normal syslog/logrotation utilities.

Comment: And if a central syslog server is being used, you have backups and a secure logging environment to boot.